# Magento 2 Payment Info Block

Tags: magento2, payment

I've made payment extension.
It works well.

Now I need to make showing payment url (below payment method name)

On 1.x I just edit info.phtml with using function **$this->isEmailContext()**

How can I make it now?
And how to get current order?

Comment: I have searched payment info block, but have found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy - just use $block->getInfo()->getOrder(); for order